# Tax implications when paying off debt with a non-monetary asset

Tags: united-kingdom, capital-gains-tax

Let's assume I take a loan and the lender requires the interest to be paid in a non-monetary asset, which we shall call XYZ.

In the eyes of HMRC, XYZ is considered to be equivalent to company shares, so taxpayers should follow the usual [capital gains tax rules](https://www.gov.uk/hmrc-internal-manuals/capital-gains-manual/cg51560#IDATX33F) when working out their gains after acquiring and disposing of XYZ.

Now, let's further assume that I have an existing pool of XYZ and decide to repay my loan. I pay the principal fully in cash but I am required to pay the interest in XYZ, so I do that.

How should this interest repayment be handled? As a disposal of XYZ? This [gov.uk doc](https://www.gov.uk/capital-gains-tax) indicates that "swapping it for something else" is also considered a disposal, but this is a bit vague in my case.